# Which floating point exceptions make NaNs?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17, nan, floating-point-exceptions

Of the five floating point exception categories defined in C++, namely:

1. `FE_INEXACT`
2. `FE_DIVBYZERO`
3. `FE_UNDERFLOW`
4. `FE_OVERFLOW`
5. `FE_INVALID`

...which of these can result in a `NaN` value?

Also - are there any operations that can result in a `NaN` value, but not trigger one of these exceptions?

Comment: Regarding your second question, there is an overload for ```quiet_NaN``` which is noexcept (actually the only one since C++11): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN

Comment: @Jose: I don't think `noexcept` is relevant here.  Floating point exceptions and regular C++ exceptions are unrelated.

Comment: Might want to specify whether you’re referring to the vague guarantees provided by the C++ standard, or by the more stringent guarantees of those which assert `is_iec559`.

Comment: @Sneftel: An answer for each of those two cases would be welcome.

Comment: It's not two cases, it's one case and a thousand other cases.

Comment: @Eljay: By the two cases I mean whether `is_iec559` is `true` or `false` as @Sneftel highlighted.